# Drupal 7 Token Replacements

Tags: php, drupal-7, token

What is the proper way to store token replacements in a variable? Or should i even bother and call them directly?

Things like:

```
$author_uid = [node:author:uid];
$name = [node:title];
$picture = [node:field-image-upload:file];
$link = [node:url];
```

Are giving me an error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':'
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Also in regards to this line:

```
$picture = [node:field-image-upload:file];
```

What I'm really trying to get is the url link to that image file. How can I do this with a token?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to store a token in a variable, you should write `$author_uid = "[node:author:uid]";`

Note that **the token is just a string**.
As noted in [the documentation for `token.inc`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!token.inc/7), the token system is an...

> API functions for replacing placeholders in text with meaningful
>   values.

If you want the URL Link to the image file, you could do:

```
$picture = token_replace('[node:field-image-upload:file]', array('node' => $node));
```

Note that you would need to already have the `$node` object to pass into the [token replacement function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!token.inc/function/token_replace/7).

Comment: you saved my day :)

Comment: I have it like "$test = token_replace('[site:current-page]', array('site' => $site));" but in variable $test this value is coming up:"Property current_page"